# Rest Framework, how to flatten simple many to many relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a `ManytoManyField()` called `books` which serializes in the nested format as shown below:

```
books = BooksSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

"books": [
{
    "id": 12
},
{
    "id": 13
},
```

Since I'm only serializing 1 field and that field is unique. How do I flatten the field to output a simple list?

```
"books": [12, 13]
```

Comment: You can use `SerializerMethodField` to write your custom serialization logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` and provide custom serialization logic there:

```
class LibrarySerializer(model.ModelSerializer):
    books = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_books(self, library):
        return [book.id for book in library.books]
```

Comment: Thanks, i have got this far, but this seems to trigger a huge amount of queries.  My original queryset does a prefetch on books, but when doing this operation in the method a new query is done for every object.  [edit] ah ok, as a list comp it's ok, i was doing another filter.  Thanks

Comment: @rix yeah, another filter would have nullified the prefetched data. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for a read-only `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, which comes included with DRF and is the default automatically generated field for relations.